# Where is the NetBeans 8 dictionary located?

Tags: netbeans, dictionary, filepath, netbeans-8

NetBeans have the concept of a "project" specific dictionary and a "private" dictionary. I happened to add a misspelled word into one of those (yeah I can't even remember which one, I was to fast, hence the error).

Where are these dictionaries stored on my Windows 8 x64 machine (I will edit this question in time as answers provide the path to other systems)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is for Windows 7 x64, but it's probably similar for Windows 8:

The project-specific dictionary is stored within the file `project.xml`, which is inside the NetBeans project folder for your project. i.e.:

```
[path/to/your/project]/nbproject/project.xml
```

In this file, the custom words are found in `<word>` tags in project > configuration > spellchecker-wordlist

The private dictionaries are stored in:

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\[version_number]\
```

So for me that was:

```
C:\Users\Myname\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0.1\private-dictionary-en_GB
```

The private dictionary is a file containing the words separated by newlines.

I had the same problem as @Martin (it's too easy to accidentally add a word) and I ended up doing a text search of the entire hard drive for these locations.

Comment: The most obvious place was the one I didn't look in, thanks

Answer (score 1):

as you can find here:http://forums.netbeans.org/ptopic37142.html

Dictionary files are in "*/ide/modules/dict/*" folder

With Windows 8.1 x64, the path is:

*C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0\ide\modules\dict*

Comment: I was looking for the "project" and "private" specific dictionaries. These I cannot find in the folder you point out. In the link you refer to, someone talks about a "private-dictionary-en_US" file in folder "%USER_HOME%/.netbeans/X.X/". I can't find this folder nor can I find the private dictionary file anywhere. My main problem is just like the problem this guy in the thread had, I added to my private- or project based dictionary a wrong word that I cannot get rid of.

Answer (score 0):

in ubuntu the file exists in

```
~/.netbeans/[version-number]/private-dictionary-en_US
```